# Update a column of XMLTYPE using a SQL query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g

I have to update the limit_xml column in the below table:

```
TEST:
id        NUMBER(32);
limit_xml XMLTYPE;

UPDATE test
SET limit_xml = '<XML>'
WHERE id = 20;
```

I do not intend to replace certain parts in the XML but the complete XML.

But the above sql does not work. I assume it is due to the large XML content. The XML contains more than 200 characters.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Alex Poole - Hi Alex. Can you please assist me here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create table xml_tab(xml XMLType);

Table created.

SQL> insert into xml_tab values ('
  2  <Common>
  3   <Field>
  4    <Label>Begin Date </Label>
  5    <Value Name="BEG_DATE">02.05.2006</Value>
  6    </Field>
  7   <Field>
  8    <Label>End Date</Label>
  9    <Value Name="END_DATE">01.06.2016</Value>
 10   </Field>
 11   <Field>
 12    <Label>type</Label>
 13    <Value Name="TYPE">Example</Value>
 14   </Field>
 15  </Common>
 16  ');

1 row created.

SQL> UPDATE xml_taB
  2     SET xml = updateXML(xml,
  3                         '/DATA/Common/Field/Value[@Name="END_DATE"]/text()',
  4                         '02.06.2017');

1 row updated.
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit. But as I mentioned I want to replace the complete XML not certain parts of it.

Comment: You mean updating the entire XML doc? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb04cre.htm#i1024833